# jquery .click does not trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a (probably) very easy problem to fix, but I can't figure out what's wrong. I try to run .click() jquery but it does not trigger. I think it's because the actual DOM items get created dynamically with javascript (does it matter?).

the dynamically created content is:

```
<div class="rPics">
    <div class="class">
        <canvas id="canSSJ01" class="thumbCan" width="600" height="720"></canvas>
        <p class="cDID hidden">SSJ01</p>
    </div>
    <div class="class">
        <canvas id="canSSJ02" class="thumbCan" width="600" height="720"></canvas>
        <p class="cDID hidden">SSJ02</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.class').click(function(){
  globalJID = $(this).children(".cDID").text();
  console.debug("clicked thCC: "+globalJID);
});
```

Now when I check chrome, it does not trigger the .click function at all :(

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Event delegation. Google it

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the items are created dynamically, you can use event delegation with [jquery .on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function (){   //Here use `on`
  globalJID = $(this).children(".cDID").text();
  console.debug("clicked thCC: "+globalJID);
});
```

If you're with an oldie jquery version, you can accomplish the same with `live`

```
 $(document).live('click', function (){
```

Comment: Hi Edgar. Your answers are great, but can I request that you don't add thanks or "hope this helps" to every one? They will [generally be edited out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34464/questions-with-lots-of-thank-you-answers) anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If the elements are created dynamically, then you want to use

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.class', function () {
```

Also you might want to rethink having the class name being `class`.

Refer **[here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** for the documentation.
Refer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)** for a similar question.

Comment: the name of class was changed for easier read in here actual class name is thumbCanCon.. but I thought it would be easier to see what I'm talking about when the class is short and clear

Comment: @TomaszGolinski - OK, glad to hear that the name is not class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method and learn [**event delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), for dynamically created elements. Bind event with nearest static container

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function(){
  globalJID = $(this).children(".cDID").text();
  console.debug("clicked thCC: "+globalJID);
});
```